# Selenium Not Catching Timeout Exception

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception, phantomjs

I have just started with Selenium & quite like it so far but have come across an issue that is driving me insane! No matter what I do, I cannot seem to catch a "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException was unhandled by user code" exception.

The code I am using is:

```
   Private Sub WaitForLoad(ByRef driver As PhantomJSDriver, ByVal Timeout As TimeSpan, ByVal FindField As IWebElement)
    Try
        Dim wait As WebDriverWait = New WebDriverWait(driver, Timeout)
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(FindField))
    Catch ex As OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException
        MessageBox.Show("1")
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    Catch ex As WebDriverException
        MessageBox.Show("2")
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    Catch ex As System.TimeoutException
        MessageBox.Show("3")
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("4")
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I simply have the message boxes in there as I have been trying to catch all exception types to check which one would actually catch it but none will.

I am calling the function with, E.g.

```
WaitForLoad(driver, WaitTimeout, driver.FindElementByName("search"))
```

I have seen a few other questions similar to this on SO but all with the answer of "add WebDriverTimeoutException" which I have done with no luck as of yet. Hopefully somebody else has overcome this issue before I spend another few hours working out this issue!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling "Enable Unmanaged Code Debugging" via Visual Studio this issue was resolved.